# How can i remove the shadow of the toolbar?

Tags: android-studio

[I wanna remove the shadow or the line after the name of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzjX6.png)
When i put that code 
    
        
        0dp
     in XML i get the following error: invalid parent reference 'style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.

Comment: did you use the tabLayout?

Comment: yes, i did that

Comment: so put your code plz to edit is

Comment: I didn't know how can i put it on stackoverflow cos I'm newcomer here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use toolbar widget to set the elevation same as your TabLayout, try to add toolbar above your TabLayout (im using LinearLayout) like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RELIGIOUS" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ANCIENT" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MUSEUMS" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EVENTS" />
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

also, you need new style to remove default toolbar, let say we have this new style

```
<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    // this 2 code to remove toolbar and we can use custom toolbar
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

then use this style to your activity, example :

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"> // this
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

last, define our new toolbar in activity.

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I wanna use to remove the shadow without removing default toolbar.

Comment: I mean if i can remove it in style XML file

Comment: I did every thing u tell me and i got error mess says view pager has stopped

Comment: view pager has stopped

Comment: In my code is for the toolbar and tablayout, you need to add viewpager below the tablayout